Ethers.js: "contract runner does not support sending transactions" Error When Sending Ether in Contract Function
I'm encountering an error while trying to send Ether using Ethers.js in my decentralised Application. I have a Solidity function sendMoneyToCustomer that is marked as payable, but when I call it using Ethers.js, I get the following error:
Error: contract runner does not support sending transactions (operation="sendTransaction", code=UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION, version=6.13.3)
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.8;

contract LoyaltyPoints {
    
    struct UserProfile {
        string username;
        string role;
    }

    mapping(address => UserProfile) private profiles;
    mapping(address => uint256) private balances;
    mapping(bytes32 => PurchaseRequest) private purchaseRequests;

    struct PurchaseRequest {
        address supermarket;
        uint256 amount;
    }

    modifier onlyRegisteredSupermarket() {
        UserProfile memory userProfile = profiles[msg.sender];
        require(bytes(userProfile.username).length > 0, "Supermarket does not exist");
        require(keccak256(bytes(userProfile.role)) == keccak256(bytes("supermarket")), "Not a Supermarket");
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyRegisteredCustomer() {
        UserProfile memory userProfile = profiles[msg.sender];
        require(bytes(userProfile.username).length > 0, "Customer does not exist");
        require(keccak256(bytes(userProfile.role)) == keccak256(bytes("customer")), "Not a Customer");
        _;
    }

    error InsufficientBalance(uint requested, uint available);

    function setProfile(string memory _username, string memory _role) public {
        profiles[msg.sender] = UserProfile(_username, _role);
    }

    function getProfile(address userAddress) public view returns (UserProfile memory) {
        return profiles[userAddress];
    }

    // Function to generate a QR code (purchase request) for a customer to scan and pay
    function generatePurchaseRequest(uint256 amount) public onlyRegisteredSupermarket returns (bytes32) {
        require(amount > 0, "Amount must be greater than zero");
        bytes32 qrCode = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, amount, block.timestamp));
        purchaseRequests[qrCode] = PurchaseRequest(msg.sender, amount);
        return qrCode;
    }

    // Function for customer to scan the QR code and pay
    function payWithQRCode(bytes32 qrCode) public payable onlyRegisteredCustomer {
        PurchaseRequest memory request = purchaseRequests[qrCode];
        require(request.supermarket != address(0), "Invalid QR code"); // Ensure valid request
        require(msg.value >= request.amount, "Insufficient amount sent");

        // Transfer ETH from customer to supermarket

        payable(request.supermarket).transfer(request.amount);
        
        
        // Remove the purchase request after payment is made
        delete purchaseRequests[qrCode];
    }

     function sendMoneyToCustomer(address payable customer) public payable onlyRegisteredSupermarket {
        require(customer != address(0), "Invalid customer address");
        balances[customer] += msg.value;
        customer.transfer(msg.value);
     }
}
                                                                                                                   
     import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import axios from "axios";
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import { SHOPIFY_URL} from "~~/services/global.variables";





export const useShopBrandsStore = defineStore('shopBrands', {
    state: () => ({
        name: "",
        full_name: "",
        my_profile : null,
        contractAddress: "0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3",
        abi : [
            {
              "inputs": [
                {
                  "internalType": "uint256",
                  "name": "requested",
                  "type": "uint256"
                },
                {
                  "internalType": "uint256",
                  "name": "available",
                  "type": "uint256"
                }
              ],
              "name": "InsufficientBalance",
              "type": "error"
            },
            {
              "inputs": [
                {
                  "internalType": "uint256",
                  "name": "amount",
                  "type": "uint256"
                }
              ],
              "name": "generatePurchaseRequest",
              "outputs": [
                {
                  "internalType": "bytes32",
                  "name": "",
                  "type": "bytes32"
                }
              ],
              "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
              "type": "function"
            },
            {
              "inputs": [
                {
                  "internalType": "address",
                  "name": "userAddress",
                  "type": "address"
                }
              ],
              "name": "getProfile",
              "outputs": [
                {
                  "components": [
                    {
                      "internalType": "string",
                      "name": "username",
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                      "internalType": "string",
                      "name": "role",
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  ],
                  "internalType": "struct LoyaltyPoints.UserProfile",
                  "name": "",
                  "type": "tuple"
                }
              ],
              "stateMutability": "view",
              "type": "function"
            },
            {
              "inputs": [
                {
                  "internalType": "bytes32",
                  "name": "qrCode",
                  "type": "bytes32"
                }
              ],
              "name": "payWithQRCode",
              "outputs": [],
              "stateMutability": "payable",
              "type": "function"
            },
            {
              "inputs": [
                {
                  "internalType": "address payable",
                  "name": "customer",
                  "type": "address"
                }
              ],
              "name": "sendMoneyToCustomer",
              "outputs": [],
              "stateMutability": "payable",
              "type": "function"
            },
            {
              "inputs": [
                {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "_username",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                {
                  "internalType": "string",
                  "name": "_role",
                  "type": "string"
                }
              ],
              "name": "setProfile",
              "outputs": [],
              "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
              "type": "function"
            }
          ],
        
           
    }),
    actions: {
        async connectWallet ()  {
            console.log("Ethers:", ethers);
        
                
           const provider = new ethers.BrowserProvider(window.ethereum)
                console.log("Ethers:", ethers);
                console.log("Provider:", provider);
                await provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", []);
                const signer = await provider.getSigner();
                console.log('s',signer)

                const walletAddress = await signer;

                // Save wallet address and provider in localStorage
               
                localStorage.setItem("signer", JSON.stringify(signer));
                return provider.getSigner();
            
        },
        async setProfile(signer, username, role)  {
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddress, this.abi, signer);
            const tx = await contract.setProfile(username, role);
            await tx.wait();
        },
        async getProfile (signer)  {
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddress, this.abi, signer);
            console.log('signer',signer)
            const userAddress = await signer; // Get the user's wallet address
            const profile = await contract.getProfile(userAddress);
            this.my_profile = profile
            return profile;
        },
        
        
        async generatePurchaseRequest  (signer, amount)  {
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
            const qrCode = await contract.generatePurchaseRequest(amount);
            return qrCode;
        },
        
        async payWithQRCode  (signer, qrCode, amount)  {
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, signer);
            const tx = await contract.payWithQRCode(qrCode, { value: ethers.utils.parseEther(amount) });
            await tx.wait(); 
        },
        
        async sendMoneyToCustomer  (signer, customerAddress, amount)  {
            const contract = new ethers.Contract(this.contractAddress, this.abi, signer);
            console.log('aaa',amount)
            const ethValue = ethers.parseEther(amount)
            console.log('eth',ethValue)
            const tx = await contract.sendMoneyToCustomer(customerAddress, {value: ethValue},  // Convert the amount from ETH to Wei
            );
            await tx.wait();  // Wait for the transaction to be mined
        },
        
    
       
      
       
        
      
        
     
   

 

  

     
      
        
      
   
       
    
    
       
        
      
      
    }
});   
    

Here's what I've checked so far:
The signer is correct, and I can call other non-payable functions like setProfile with the same signer.and its qorking when call setProfile

